# Conditional either-or on type constraint

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have a type constraint that is an "or" of two types instead of an "and".  An "and" is accomplished by putting a comma between the two types.  But what about an "or"?

```
class Type1<T, U>
{
    public static Type1<T, U> New<V>( V v )
        where V : T, U
    {
        return new Type1<T, U>();
    }
}
```

So in the above example, the argument passed into New() must be both a T and a U.  But I want it to be either a T **or** a U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to express the "or" constraint in the manner you described.  However you can emulate this by having two overloads one which accepts `U` and the other `T`.  These two can then feed into a common function which handles `T` or `U`

```
class Type1<T, U> {
  public static Type1<T, U> New(U p) {
    return NewCore(p);
  }

  public static Type1<T, U> New(T p) {
    return NewCore(p);
  }

  private static Type1<T, U> New(object o) {  
    ...
  }
}
```

Not quite sure what you'd want to do with the `T` or `U` parameter though.  Perhaps you could elaborate a bit

Comment: +1  I already have two public overloads of New.  So with this approach I'd have four public overloads plus the private one.  It's a lot of overloads, but anyway it'd work.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an empty marker interface and have both T and U "implement" them.  Then constrain new to any type that implements that interface.

```
public interface ITOrU { /*empty interface*/ }

public interface IT : ITOrU
{
}

public interface IU : ITOrU
{
}

class Type1<T, U>
    where T : IT
    where U : IU
{
    public static Type1<T, U> New( ITOrU v )
    {
        return new Type1<T, U>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer, thanks!  But if you add a code sample, it'd be even better.